# Node Js how to get started

Tags: node.js

I'm a newbie JavaScript programmer who wants to experiment with server side JavaScript using Node.Js on my Mac
I downloaded NodeJs and the wizard installed it, but now I can't see it in my applications?

1) How do I open it and start using it?  Do I do it from the command line? if so, how do I start?

2) Can I connect it to a MySQL database I have installed with MAMP?

Thanks if you can help

Comment: `node filename` from the command line.

Comment: I forked an incomplete ebook on github and I've added a lot of content: https://github.com/jimschubert/masteringnode It talks a bit about installing node and packages, and how to begin working with node.  Original repo for the ebook is here: https://github.com/visionmedia/masteringnode

Comment: Also, browse to _docs/book.pdf_ and click *raw*, then you don't need to clone the whole repo.  I regenerated the book about a week ago, so it's probably only missing the http server section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To start node, you open a terminal and type:

```
/path/to/node scriptname.js
```

Depending on how you installed node, the actual location of node may vary. You should figure that out. You should probably [add that path](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2621/os_x_change_path_environment_variable/) to your PATH environment variable. If you do this then you can simply type

```
node scriptname.js
```

There are plenty of samples [around the net](http://howtonode.org/hello-node). As for mysql connectivity, [check this out](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).

Answer (score 1):

I am in pretty much in the same boat as you are, and I highly recommend you to watch the meetup talk by Ryan Dahl on http://nodejs.org/

It is only about an hour long, but it pretty shows you how you can use it for your own non-blocking applications.

In terms of driver for accessing SQL, you will need to install NPM http://npmjs.org/
You can do a quick search http://search.npmjs.org/, on the support for MySQL. Because node.js is still relatively new to the scene, you will see quite a bit of choices competing to meet your goal